# TestNG + Selenium Grid, only one RC running,

Tags: testng, selenium-grid

I am using Selenium Grid with TestNG to test a website. The test-code, that i exported from the Selenium IDE works fine. My problem is, the tests are running sequential, not parallel.

Here is the code:

```
public class test{

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startSession()
    {
        ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.startSeleniumSession("localhost",4444,"*firefox","url" );
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void closeSession() throws Exception
    {
      ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.closeSeleniumSession();
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "test")
    public Object[][] test()
    {
        return new Object[][]{
        {test1,null},
        {test2,null},
        };
}

 @Test(dataProvider = "test")
 void testen(String value1, String value2) throws Exception
  {
     ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.session().open("url");
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
     ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.session().waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }

}
```

My testng.xml looks like this:

suite thread-count="5" skipfailedinvocationCounts="false" verbose="1" name="Command line suite" junit="false" parallel="methods" annotations="JDK"

What am I doing wrong? The test runs only on one Selenium RC, although more than one are started.

I hope someone can help me, it is really important.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to TestNG 5.11, which implements parallel data providers. The previous versions always invoked all the data provider calls in the same thread...

-- 
Cedric